# What's wrong with my if-else statement?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I made this simple GUI program that counts the vowels and consonants of a particular sequence of characters. The counter is okay, but I'm having a problem with the if-else statement where I had to display a message when that character is neither a vowel nor consonant... Here's the code:

```
//I initialized these variables:

    public static int vowels = 0, consonants = 0, charac = 0;
    public static String outputStr;
    public static String conso = "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz";
    public static String vow = "aeiou";

    //Here's the code for my "count" button
    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

        String userInput = jTextField1.getText();
        userInput = userInput.toUpperCase();
        conso = conso.toUpperCase();
        vow = vow.toUpperCase();
        String wordInput[] = userInput.split("");

        vowels = 0;
        consonants = 0;
        charac = 0;

        for(int i=0; i<wordInput.length; i++) {
            for(int j=0; j<5; j++) {
                char v = vow.charAt(j);
                String VL = Character.toString(v);
                if(VL.equals(wordInput[i])) {
                    vowels ++;
                    charac = 0;}
                else {
                    charac += 1; }
                }

            for(int h=0; h<21; h++) {
                char c = conso.charAt(h);
                String CL = Character.toString(c);
                if(CL.equals(wordInput[i])) {
                    consonants ++;
                    charac = 0; }
                else {
                    charac += 1; }
            }

        }

        String totalVow = Integer.toString(vowels);
        String totalCons = Integer.toString(consonants);

        jLabel5.setText(totalVow);
        jLabel6.setText(totalCons);


    //here's the if-else statement:

        if (charac == 0) {
            jLabel7.setText(" ");
        }
        else if (charac >= 1) {
            jLabel7.setText("The sequence contains invalid characters.");
        }
        if (userInput.isEmpty()) {
            jLabel7.setText("No input.");
        }
}
```

Here's what it looks like:

[image]

I entered a "sequence" of characters that does not have any special characters or digits. But it still displays the message wherein it has other characters other than the vowels and consonants. Is there something wrong with the if-else statement? Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your logic for counting invalid characters if wrong. What you do is: you increase the counter each time the character is not the character you just tested, that is, for each character in your input, the `charac` variable is increased *25* times! But then, the next time the character matches the currently tested vowel or consonant, you *reset* the `charac` variable to 0!

Instead of using two `for` loops to check for each of your vowels and consonants individually, you can use builtin String methods to check whether the current character is one of the vowels or consonants, e.g., `indexOf`. This way, the checks are reduced to a single if-statement each, making it much easier to have the "else" case for when it's neither a vowel nor a consonant.

```
for (int i = 0; i < userInput.length(); i++) {
    char c = userInput.charAt(i);
    if (vow.indexOf(c) != -1) {
        vowels++;
    } else if (conso.indexOf(c) != -1) {
        consonants++;
    } else {
        charac++; // invalid character
    }
}
```

Also, note that instead of splitting the string to an array of strings you can also use the `charAt` method.

Comment: I tried this and it worked! plus it made my code a bit shorter. thanks a lot! @tobias_k

Answer (score 4):

The problem is in the inner for loop. Every character is tested with each of 5 different vowels, so surely it will fail to match at least 4 of them, and `charac` will be incremented

```
for(int j=0; j<5; j++) {
    char v = vow.charAt(j);
    String VL = Character.toString(v);
    if(VL.equals(wordInput[i])) {
        vowels ++;
        charac = 0;}
    else {
        charac += 1;
    }
}
```

Instead, you can use the String.contains() method in place of the inner loop.

Answer (score 3):

You put irrelevant code in your loop. Your loop should like:

```
 for(int i=0; i<wordInput.length; i++) {
   char ch=wordInput.charAt(i);
   if(Character.isLetter(ch)){
     if(isVowel(ch)){// make a method which return true if char is vowel.
      vowel++;
     }
     else{
     consonent++;
     }
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You're adding to `charac` in both loops: one that looks up the consonants and the one that looks up the vowels. You'd want to use an if/else-if/else here, where only if a character is not a consonant or a vowel you add to `charac`.

Also, take a look Guava utilities. For instance, this is how you get all vowels and all consonants:

```
String vowels = "aeiou";
String consonants = "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz";
String input = "mary had a little lamb";
String allVowels = CharMatcher.anyOf(vowels).retainFrom(input);
String allConsonants = CharMatcher.anyOf(consonants).retainFrom(input);
```